# Need to convert XY values to features in feature service using ArcGIS Server JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to convert XY values in a text file which the user uploads into point features (not graphics) in a feature service using ArcGIS Server JavaScript API.
The ArcGIS server version is 10.1 and API version is 3.5

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Did you tried to search on Google ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/exp_dragdrop.html

Answer (score 1):

I would read the file, push the X/Y values in to an two dimensional array.
In a for (foreach) loop, i'd create a point feature for every X/Y value pair.

```
for(i in array){
    var point = new esri.geometry.Point(array[i][0], array[i][1])
    // do something with the point here
}
```

At the comment, you can process the point. For example, you can add them to the featureSrevice via the ["query task"](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/querytask.html).